# maven plugin not found

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-release-plugin

I have a problem with the maven plugin.

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'exec' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Documents and Settings\MAA1ARN2\.m2\repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Show the pom file which causes the problem and best show the full output and not only excerpts and please format your question correctly.

Comment: what is the maven command you are executing.

Comment: You probably want to use `maven-exec-plugin`, but you still need to provide more context. Where does this come from? Did you try to run `mvn exec:java` or `mvn exec:exec` from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException), there can be a typo in the plugin you refer to, your pom is wrong, your settings.xml is wrong, or your metadata is broken. I have also found that you can get this error if your plugin's code fails.

Comment: For me '~/.m2/settings.xml' was wrong (proxy parameters were missing)